# How to fix an error about PHPDoc on interface class

Tags: php, interface, phpstorm, phpdoc, implements

I'm working on a PHP library and I have two classes.

First one is like this:

```
/**
 * @method static A getInstance()
 */
interface A {...}
```

Second one is like this:

```
class B implements A {...}
```

`getInstance` is not defined in A, except in PHPDoc above class. Now, my IDE (PHPStorm) suggests an error, saying that I should implement `getInstance` in B.

My questions are:

1. Why they put this method in PHPDoc even though it's not declared in the interface? I doubt it's a mistake, since they used the same comment in many other classes.
2. What do you recommend? should I implement in B or should I remove the PHPDoc comment from A?

Comment: Can you attach a link to the library that contains interface A?

Comment: @MaximFedorov Of course. Here: https://github.com/oxwall/oxwall/blob/bd78b5a020c2b8580fec017910be622d157ec3fa/ow_core/storage.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the mistake because any of the classes which implement `OW_Storage` interface don't implement `getInstance()` method. You can make sure it with help [search](https://github.com/oxwall/oxwall/search?q=implements%20OW_Storage&unscoped_q=implements%20OW_Storage). It means this function isn't used.

You can remove the doc block from the interface but right way is to do pull-request in origin repository.